# How to make parameters optional when using Rails named routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I have a named route:

```
map.find '/find/:category/:state/:search_term/:permalink', :search_term=>nil, :controller=>'find', :action=>'show_match'
```

and the following URL matches it & works OK:

```
http://localhost:3000/find/cars/ca/TestSeachTerm/bumpedupphoto-test
```

but if I take out the 2nd last parameter i.e. "TestSearchTerm", then the route fails to get matched, even though I have :search_term=>nil in the route.

```
http://localhost:3000/find/cars/ca//bumpedupphoto-test
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Being trying to solve this for a few days now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after your current route:

```
map.find '/find/:category/:state/:permalink', :controller=>'find', :action=>'show_match'
```

Comment: Thanks for that.

When I put that in as a route, rails cannot seem to decide which route to use:

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
The error occurred while evaluating nil.has_key?